# Jetpack Compose: Explain to me why the list content is not updated?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I know that in Jetpack Compose you have to change the state of the passed in data in order to trigger a recomposition of the UI to update the UI with any changes. I have also read the documentation about Jetpack Compose state and ViewModels [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state). But that's a very simple example and does not cover the use case below.

Below is a conceptual scenario where I want to update the state of the list, by updating just one item's state that I wish to be reflected in the Jetpack Compose rendered part. I know I must assign a new list as data, which should trigger the recomposition and below I am using `toMutableList()` to try to achieve this. But this does not work. When I run this kind of code, recomposition does not happen and the single item's state is not updated in the list.

Could someone please explain to me why this does not work and how should I approach this?

I already know of `mutableStateListOf()`, but how should I approach this if I want to keep my view models compatible with other non-Jetpack Compose parts of my app, and thus I only want to use LiveData in my view models?

```
class Model : ViewModel() {
  private val _items = MutableLiveData(listOf<Something>())
  val items: LiveData<String> = _items

  fun update(item: Something) {
    _items.value = _items.value!!.toMutableList().map {
        if (it == item) {
           // Update item. But it's not reflected in Jetpack Compose
        }
     }
  }
}

@Composable
fun ListComponent(model: Model) {
   val items by model.items.observeAsState(emptyList())
   LazyColumn {
      items(items) { item -> 
       ...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you want to filter items conditionally then use filter instead of map. map is used to transform one type of data to another in a collection.

Comment: I want to update one item in the list. Thus, mapping over all items in the list, mutating the one I want which in the end transforms the whole list to another one. Thus, I would hope to trigger recomposition.

Comment: Yeah, it should’ve worked. May be you're missing something..

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. Good to know that at least I have understood this correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are mutating array instead of copying it. Compose needs stable equality when talking about recomposition avoidance, here i believe it can only use reference. Try copying array and then mutating the new one. I believe if you do map without `toMutableList()` it will create a copy and do exactly what you want

Comment: Sorry! I had an error in the code; the code wouldn't compile with the one I wrote there (from of top of my head). I missed the .value and added that. That's how I had in my original code and it would not trigger a recomposition for me.

Comment: @JohanPaul updated the answer, please check if that's working for you